Only my first SQL statement is working, the following statements appear to be broken
I am a student creating a dynamic website for a school project and I'm attempting to implement a checkout button which selects all items from the basket and inserts each of them into a new order. However, the only SQL statement which I can see (in the database) has been processed is the first one:
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (customerId, orderDate, orderStatus ) VALUE ($customerId, CURRENT_DATE(), 1)";
Please keep in mind I am not experienced in PHP and SQL as this is my first time using both.
My desired outcome of this code would be to:

Insert customerId, current date, and orderstatus into orders table
Get each item from the customer's basket and turn this into a list called $finalBasket
Add a new row in the 'order items' table containing orderId, productId, quantity, and unitPrice for each item in $finalBasket

(the following steps I haven't attempting to code yet):

When all basket items have been recorded as an order, delete all the basketItems from the customer's basket

Confirm with user that their order has been created by updating the message on-screen.

Once order is complete, display the basket with no items and update the message on-screen to read "Order number (orderId) processed"


All the following statements appear not to be functioning as intended. This is the rest of the PHP code for the checkout button (It is not finished yet, but the parts which I have written aren't working - other than the first SQL statement - ) Please let me know if you need to see other parts of the code to get a better insight into my problem as I don't know what could be causing it. I am also not getting any error messages showing up on my webpage so I can't see the problem:
IF ($method=="POST") {

                                    if (isset($_POST['checkoutButton'])) {

                                        $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (customerId, orderDate, orderStatus ) VALUE ($customerId, CURRENT_DATE(), 1)";

                                        

                                        $orderId = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";

                                        ?>







                                        <?php

                                        
                                        
                                        

                                        if ($conn->query($sql)) {
                                            $message = "Order Pending";
                                            $conn->commit();

                                            $sql = "SELECT basketItemId, productId, quantity, unitPrice FROM basketitems WHERE basketId = $basketId";

                                            

                                            $finalBasket = $conn->query($sql);

                                            WHILE ($finalBasketList = $finalBasket->fetch_assoc()) {
                                                $productId = $finalBasketList["productId"];
                                                $quantity = $finalBasketList["quantity"];
                                                $unitPrice = $finalBasketList["unitPrice"];
                                                $sql = "INSERT INTO orderitems (orderId, productId, quantity, unitPrice) VALUE ($orderId, $productId, $quantity, $unitPrice)";
                                                if ($conn->query($sql)) {
                                                    $message = "Successfully began Order";
                                                };


                                            }
                                        } ELSE {
                                            $message = "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                                            $basketId = 0;


                                        }

                                    }

                                    

                                }


Your code has some major issues: primarily a lack of parameterization in your SQL, and therefore probably syntactically incorrect and dangerous. Also you are not checking for errors inside the loop. You are also not committing after the loop. Also I don't think it's supported to have two active statements on the connection, and you don't need that anyway as you can do a single INSERT ... SELECT ... without any loops. And $orderId = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()"; isn't going to work, that's just a string, use $conn->insert_id instead.
